# Transloadit Thumbnail Result Image Has Wrong File Extension Capitalization

Tags: ios, transloadit

I am using transloadit to generate a thumbnail image sent from an iOS app that saves both the original image and the thumbnail to Amazon S3. The files get get saved out correctly with one exception. The file name for the thumbnail does not retain the capitalization of the original filename for the file extension, i.e. JPG vs jpg. Here is my template:

[image]

I am using the fields to generate the custom path I want--which works fine, however, the output from the "store_thumb" step has this difference:

[image]

Is there any way to retain the capitalization? I realize I can just force all of my filenames from the app to lowercase, however, I thought maybe I am just doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm part of Transloadit's developer support team.

First of all, let me assure you there's nothing wrong with what you're doing. Secondly, I've asked our engineers about the issue and we realized it's a limitation caused by our special usage of some of the conversion tools.

We'll do our best to address this on future versions, but we cannot commit on a date. So for now if it's causing you trouble, we recommend using lowercase letters.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did just resort to lowercase letters which will work fine for my needs. I just found it strange that it didn't pass through with the same capitalization since I was using explicit field identifiers like file.name. Thanks again.